# Is it possible to send email using pop3 protocols?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, pop3

Is there any possible ways to send email using pop3 protocols?.

Comment: pop3 is for retrieving emails.

Comment: in general: smtp is for sending

Comment: Why is this question is off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SMTP** is for sending mails and **POP3** is for receiving.

> I don't know this is possible or not.

Definitely not possible.

Comment: Are you confirmed, pop3 protocols only used for receiving mails?.

Comment: The first result of Google says, 'POP3 is an internet-based standard for retrieval of e-mail by a user from an e-mail server.'

Comment: @Naveen what makes you ask this, what situation are you facing? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran : I am trying to fetch the mails from pop3 works fine and  i don't know, is it possible to send reply to the mails using same pop3 protocol..  That's why asked...

Answer (score 0):

Mail is sent using SMTP and not POP3.